# Dijkstra's algorithm- why every time extract the vertex with smallest priority?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am learning Dijkstra's algorithm to find shortest path. And I noticed that there is a priority queue to help extract the vertex with lowest priority in the vertex set. Will the algorithm still work if I **pick a vertex regardless of priority**, instead of the one with lowest priority, from the vertex set? **If yes, what about the time complexity?**

The original Dijkstra's algorithm from Wikipedia is like:

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
    dist[source] ← 0                                

    create vertex set Q

    for each vertex v in Graph:           
        if v ≠ source
            dist[v] ← INFINITY                      
            prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                     

    Q.add_with_priority(v, dist[v])


    while Q is not empty:                          
        u ← Q.extract_min()                        
        for each neighbor v of u:                  
            alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v) 
            if alt < dist[v]
                dist[v] ← alt
                prev[v] ← u
                Q.decrease_priority(v, alt)

    return dist[], prev[]
```

After making modifications to pick a vertex regardless of priority(**please note that there is an "add" after relaxation**):

```
function DijkstraVariant(Graph, source):
    dist[source] ← 0                                

    create vertex set Q

    for each vertex v in Graph:           
        if v ≠ source
            dist[v] ← INFINITY                      
            prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                     

    Q.just_add(v)                  // Don't care about the priority


    while Q is not empty:                          
        u ← Q.random_pick()         // Don't care about the priority        
        for each neighbor v of u:                 
            alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v) 
            if alt < dist[v]
                dist[v] ← alt
                prev[v] ← u
                Q.just_add(v)  // Don't care about the priority

    return dist[], prev[]
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not work. It will yield a path, but it is no longer guaranteed to be the shortest.

The priority is required to account for non uniform weights, with a plain FIFO queue it will only work if all edge weights are equal. It becomes a plain broad first search.

With a random selection, instead of priority, the algorithm detoriates further, down to the level of a depth first search. That also removes all the guarantees the BFS provided, such as finding any existing path even in infinite graphs in finite time.

Comment: Would you like to come up with an example to disproof the modified version?

Comment: @LazyBoy Quite simple, just take a ring shaped graph where start and end are connected by a single edge with weight 1000 on the one side, and a chain of 100 edges with each a weight of 1 on the other. Your randomized algorithm now has a chance of 1/2^100 for taking the shortest path, and in all other cases it will fall for the edge with the high cost.

Comment: Are you saying this graph? [link to graph](http://graphonline.ru/en/?graph=XTnfWhVTYOkGSXNu)

Comment: @LazyBoy That is not a ring. Connect node 2 to node 0 instead of node 1, declare node 0 the origin and node 1 the goal.